# Why does Kivy not run when I try to add a TextInput box?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

So the problem i'm having is my Kivy application won't startup up if there is a TextInput field within the application. (I'm using Pycharm Community Edition)

An application with just Labels will run fine.

There are no errors, it's just the window for the application will not pop up like it normally would when just using Labels.

This is the code i'm trying to run:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

and this is the console log when running this code:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/camcamyoung125/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-11-23_99.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/camcamyoung125/.local/lib/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.3 (main, Jul 23 2023, 15:10:19) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/camcamyoung125/.local/lib/python3.11/bin/python3.11"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 21.2.6'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Mesa/X.org'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'virgl (Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2))'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
```

The console log just ends there and the application window doesn't pop up.

I've tried messing with the interpreter but from what I can gather its not an interpreter issue because Kivy runs fine when not using TextInputs.

Any advice or steps I could try would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**

So it turns out the problem is with Pycharm. Using a different IDE, like Visual Code, was a work around for me.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me in Pycharm v2023.2 using Python v3.10.12 and kivy v2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the IDE is not supposed to change the behavior of Kivy or any other library you use. The change of IDE probably modified your current Python environment (to VSCode), allowing your code to run.

I can confirm that the code perfectly runs both in Pycharm and in VSCode. By default, Pycharm uses its own virtual environment, contrariwise to VSCode; that might have caused the issue.

Here is my full log in Pycharm for Python 3.11 with Kivy library 2.2.1:

```bash
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Agathe\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-12-16_64.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.6.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "H:\Documents\Private\Paul\Programmation\StackOverFlow\venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.7 (tags/v3.11.7:fa7a6f2, Dec  4 2023, 19:24:49) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "H:\Documents\Private\Paul\Programmation\StackOverFlow\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 527.56'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```